# populating a temp table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to populate my temp table (`emp_department_1`) with 4 columns (`fname, minit, lname, bdate`) from my exsisting table (employee). Where the `dno=1` from the employee table. Any suggestions?

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
| Fname    | Minit | Lname   | SSN       | Bdate      | Address                  | Sex  | Salary | Superssn  | Dno |
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
| John     | B     | Smith   | 123456789 | 1955-01-09 | 731 Fondren, Cary, NC    | M    |  31500 | 333445555 |   5 |
| Franklin | T     | Wong    | 333445555 | 1945-12-08 | 638 Voss, Cary, NC       | M    |  42000 | 888665555 |   5 |
| Alicia   | J     | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 1958-07-19 | 3321 Castle, Apex, NC    | F    |  25000 | 987654321 |   4 |
| Jennifer | S     | Wallace | 987654321 | 1931-06-20 | 291 Berry, Garner, NC    | F    |  43000 | 888665555 |   4 |
| Rameish  | K     | Naraya  | 666884444 | 1952-09-15 | 975 Fire Oak, Angier, NC | M    |  39900 | 333445555 |   5 |
| Joyce    | A     | English | 453453453 | 1962-07-31 | 5631 Rice, Raleigh, NC   | F    |  26250 | 333445555 |   5 |
| Ahmad    | V     | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 1959-03-29 | 980 Dallas, Cary, NC     | M    |  25000 | 987654321 |   4 |
| James    | E     | Borg    | 888665555 | 1927-11-10 | 450 Stone, Cary, NC      | M    |  55000 | NULL      |   1 |
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
```

James E Borg is the only one where dno=1.

Comment: Thanks michael, I couldn't figure out how to clean that up.

Comment: Highlight the code block and ctl-k or click the `{ }` button in the editor.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Additionally inline code  like `SELECT this FROM that` are done by enclosing the string in backquotes.  When making large code blocks, you can indent 4 spaces, but there must be a blank space above and below the indented code block.  ctl-k does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You merely need a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...FROM` statement. It is recommended to list the columns in `()`, assuming the order of columns in `emp_department_1` does not exactly match the order I have the `SELECT` in.

```
INSERT INTO emp_department_1 (fname, minit, lname, bdate)
  SELECT fname, minit, lname, bdate FROM employee WHERE dno = 1
```

Review the [MySQL syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) on the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax.

#### Update

Since this is to be a temporary table, not yet created, use a [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE emp_department_1
   SELECT fname, minit, lname, bdate FROM employee WHERE dno = 1
```

It is not necessary to define the column types in the temporary table, though you can if needed, and also create indexes if needed.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE emp_department_1 (
  fname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  minit VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  lname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  bdate DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fname, lname, bdate) /* not that you would actually do this */
) SELECT fname, minit, lname, bdate FROM employee WHERE dno = 1
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't mention, but the temp table hasn't been created yet and the temp table needs to be populated during creation.

Comment: Excellent! Now care to share how to make my code look better so I won't look so bad posting?